# Aplication freezing right after splash screen (Delphi Berlin Android)

Tags: delphi, orientation, firemonkey, freeze

I've made a simple app on Embarcadero Delphi Berlin and I've being compiling it directly to a smartphone (Samsung Galaxy E7) to test, but most of the time when it shows the first Form the application freezes, only a TBannerAd works, I must rotate the phone and change the actual orientation for the app to unfreeze. Someone knows what may be causing that? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It would help understand the issue and provide possible solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with Tokyo now, it was there from the beginning of Tokyo, so I switched back to Berlin upd2, and it show up there. Download and reinstall iso for Berlin upd2. Make sure no virus or firewalls are active. Uninstall all of Berlin, and delete and remaining Berlin files using Windows Explorer, i.e. Berlin is v18 in Program Files x86 under embarcadero. Use the defaults FireMonkey chooses when adding the Android SDK. It like v23 of Android SDK. That fixed it on my system.